# A frase "ela quer conquistar eles com seu amor" está correta?

Tags: verbos, concordância-verbal, frases

Num vídeo ouvi a seguinte frase:

> Ela quer conquistar eles com seu amor.

Não deveria ser "Ela quer conquistá-los com seu amor"?

Comment: Erros na língua falada são muito comuns, tanto ao vivo quanto em vídeos.  Em tempo, "seu" não é escrito com letra maiúscula.  Pensei que fosse erro de digitação, mas ocorreu mais de uma vez.

Comment: Grato pela actualização

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Depende!**

Se tens em vista o Português Padrão Culto, a frase está "errada", o correto seria:

> *"Ela quer conquistá-los com seu amor"*

Porém, certos dialetos ―especialmente no Brasil― têm a forma do pronome de objeto da terceira pessoa do plural "eles". Em tais variantes a frase "ela quer conquistar eles com seu amor" é totalmente gramatical.
Nestes dialetos, o que define que "eles" é objeto da frase é a ordem dos elementos: portanto a marcação deixa de ser morfológica e passa a ser apenas sintática; e o verbo "querer" deve então concordar com o sujeito "ela", flexionando-se, pois, à terceira pessoa do singular.